# java.util.MissingResourceException :Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

Initially,I make a request and received this error -

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException:Read timed out.

After some time again,I submit the request,and I got -

> java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle
>
> java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key JBAS014516: Failed to acquire a
>   permit

within 5 MINUTES.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Include sample code which generates mentioned errors.

Answer (score 0):

This tends to happen when the configured EJB pool is exhausted. This means that all EJBs are currently being used. You probably have invocations within your EJBs that are taking a long time to run. In your case, 5 minutes or longer. Hope this helped!